# sinatra HEAD method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'd like to return json(string) for http HEAD method on sinatra.
But It seems that sinatra doesn't return any response body for HEAD requests.

I tried this code.

```
require 'sinatra'

head "/" do
   "HEAD"
end
```

And I did `curl -X HEAD 'http://localhost:4567/'`.
But the command doesn't return for a while and finally throws a error below.

```
$ curl -X HEAD 'http://localhost:4567/'
curl: (18) transfer closed with 5 bytes remaining to read
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `get` rather than `head` at line 3?  Unsure what you are trying to do, but as regards headers, [this documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Setting%20Body,%20Status%20Code%20and%20Headers) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'd like to process http HEAD method request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a perfectly valid Sinatra `head` route.  The problem is with your curl statement.

```
curl -X HEAD 'http://localhost:4567/'
```

-X HEAD is not what you want; it will not print headers and will expect some specification of expected bytes transmission stated in Content-Length.

Instead you want the following.

```
curl -I http://localhost:4567/
```